# Regex to remove first words in url

Tags: java, regex

I have a URL: `api.api-7-53b34rt.dev1.test.com`

What should be a regex to receive `dev1.test.com`

Where `dev1` can be changed (to `dev2` or `test1` etc.)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm stuck with finding the regex that will remove the beginning of the url (api.api-7-53b34rt - hash in digits can be different each time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex [`.*\.([^\.]+\.test\.com$)`](https://regex101.com/r/tiA1Xo/1) which mean get one or more non dot `[^\.]+` ends by `.test.com` `\.test\.com$`

you can use replaceAll to get the expected output :

```
String text = "api.api-7-53b34rt.dev1.test.com";
text = text.replaceAll(".*\\.([^\\.]+\\.test\\.com$)", "$1");
```

---

**Inputs**

```
api.api-7-53b34rt.dev1.test.com
api.api-7-53b34rt.dev2.test.com
api.api-7-53b34rt.test1.test.com
```

**Outputs**

```
dev1.test.com
dev2.test.com
test1.test.com
```